# Generating hash-ids from autoincremented primary key?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, hashids

When defining model I can generate uuid like this :

```
class Blah(Model):
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   uuid = Column(String,  default=lambda: str(uuid.uuid4()), unique=True)
```

but what I want is to generate hashid based on the primary key, something like this (pseudo code):
(https://github.com/davidaurelio/hashids-python)

```
class Blah(Model):
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   uuid = Column(String,  default=lambda: Hashids().encode(pk_id), unique=True)
```

the problem is I can't use generated PK from inside python function !!

How can I achieve that ???

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: u cant do : Hashids().encode(<!pk_id!>), afaik

Comment: If your DB supports sequences, you can set the primary key to have a default value of `my_hash_function(nextval("my_sequence"))`. You'll have to reimplement the hash function in whatever DB you're using.

Comment: I am curious: why would you want to have both ID and hash(ID) in the database? Isn't that just redundant data?

Comment: So that I show to the web-user opaque ID, instead the db-row id

Comment: Well you can still just have the string ID as the primary key without the integer primary key.

Comment: of course i can, but this does not solve the problem of monotone increasing id. And also int ID is easier for foreign key, etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `session.flush()` to get the primary key that is allocated.

```
db.session.add(blah)
db.session.flush()
blah.uuid = hashids.encode(blah.id)
db.session.add(blah)        
db.session.commit()
```